# Consider the infinite sequence $ \ \ 1,2,4,8,16,...............\ $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the infinite sequence $ \ \ 1,2,4,8,16,............... $

Give the generating function in closed form *(i.e., not as an infinite sum and use the most general choice of form for general term of each sequence)*.

**Answer:**

I am little confused which one is to be written among the two answer :

(i)  *generating function* $=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^n x^{n} \ $

(ii) $ a_n=2^n , \ \ n=0,1,2,3,....... $

Someone please respond me about the correct one of the above two options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the generating function
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^nx^n$$
and are supposed to write it in a closed form.
Assuming that $x$ is properly chosen (or not caring about that at all if you are working with formal power series), we can rewrite this as
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^nx^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (2x)^n = \frac{1}{1-2x}.$$

The last one is a closed form and most likely what you are supposed to find.

Comment: if I write $ a_n=2^n , \ \ n=0,1,2,..... \ $

Comment: @mabmath If that comment is supposed to be a question, there is something missing (the question mark, for example, but also some content...).

Answer (score 3):

The generating function is the sum in your choice (1), but they said "in [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)", so you need to use your knowledge of series to rewrite that function of $x$ without an infinite sum.

Comment: have you noticed the term written within the bracket saying $ \  use \ \ the \ \ most \ general \ choice \ of \ form \ for \ general \ term \ of \ each \ sequence \ $

Comment: @mabmath, Yes. I read it, and assumed it meant in context "interpret the sequence as power of 2, not just something silly like 1,2,4,8,16,16,16,16,... or [1,2,4,8,16,31,...](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleDivisionbyChords.html)